# Why do we need projection in the definition of the Stokes operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, orthonormal, laplacian

$\DeclareMathOperator{\div}{div}$
$\def\bu{\mathbf{u}}$
Let $D$ be the square $[0,1]^2$ and consider the following space:
$$
V:=\{\bu: \bu\in H^2(D)^2, \div \bu=0, u|_{\partial D}=0 \}.
$$

Introduce also 
$$
H:=\{\bu: \bu\in L^2(D)^2, \div \bu=0\}.
$$

Then the Stokes operator is defined as an operator $V\to H$ as 
$$
A\bu:=-P_L\Delta\bu,
$$
where $P_L$ is the projection on $H$.

I don't understand, why the Stokes operator is not equal to minus Laplacian? Indeed, if $\bu\in V$, then $\div \bu=0$ and thus
$$
\div \Delta\bu=u^1_{xxx}+u^1_{yyx}+u^2_{xxy}+u^2_{yyy}=(u^1_x+u^2_y)_{xx}+(u^1_x+u^2_y)_{yy}=\Delta\div\bu=0.
$$
In this case, $\Delta \bu\in H$ and thus the projection is not needed.

Question: what is wrong in my reasoning? Why the Stokes operator is not equal to Laplacian?
Related question: Can one write explicitly the eigenfunctions of Stokes operator in this simple situation? At least can maybe one bound $\lambda_1$, the smallest eigenvalue, from below?

Comment: What are the extra exponents $2$ ($H^2(D)^2$, $L^2(D)^2$)??

Comment: @TedShifrin $\mathbf{u}=(u_1,u_2)$ is a vector. Each of its 2 coordinates $u_1$ and $u_2$ belongs to $H^2(D)$. Thus, $\mathbf{u}\in H^2(D)^2$.

Comment: Oh, I see ... So, offhand, my answer to your question is that you need $C^3$ to interchange partial derivatives, and you don't have $C^3$ functions.

Comment: @TedShifrin Then why in the periodic case (periodic boundary conditions) the Stokes operator is equal to Laplacian?

Comment: Hint: In the definition of $H$, in what sense is the divergence equal to zero?

Comment: @maxmilgram In the standard distributional sense: $div \mathbf{u}=0$ if for any smooth function $\phi$ we have $(\int u^1 \phi_x+u^2\phi_y)=0$. I don't see why you call it a "hint".

Comment: Did you consider the boundary terms in the integration by parts?

Comment: @maxmilgram Well, $u$ is an $L_2$ function, so we cannot define $u$ at the set of measure zero. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: The computation of the divergence of the laplacian can only be done in a weak sense. There, you should get boundary terms (using the trace operator) which will (depending on your choice of test functions) vanish or not vanish. My assumption is that for the periodic case these boundary terms vanish automatically while they don't for your presented case.

Comment: @maxmilgram thanks for the explanations, but i guess this is exactly what I do not understand. If a function $u$ is in $L_2$ then we cannot say what are its values on the set of Lebesgue measure zero. How then can we define its trace?

Comment: In the calculation you should not get traces of $L^2$ functions. Remember that $u$ is in $H^2$ so the trace of $u$ and its first order derivatives are well defined.